# Setting focus to a grandchild using refs in React

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to be able to set focus to a textbox located in a grandchild using refs. I run into an error when I try to chain the refs together. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

My limitations are: focus needs to be set by the grandparent and the input element ref needs to be able to be used internally.

Here's a link to a generic implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9ow54zw15y

Comment: Indeed... nested refs are someway chaotic. Why you need to to this from a parent?
Also: remember that if using the new `createRef` you must access refs using `.current`. See  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs
I also suggest you to use the (again new) forwardRef: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: It's a weird case where we're using a component that's a special textbox and in the case that there's only one we want to be able to focus it, but there could also be multiple occurrences of it, so we don't want to leave it to the textbox to focus on enter.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this up here for anyone who runs into this problem. I neglected to use `.current` so it should have been `this.parentRef.current.grandChildRef.current.inputRef.current.focus();`

A bit of a monster but it gets the job done!

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs